# Windows 8 PhoneGap FileTransfer fails with text file

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-store-apps, fiddler

I am trying to upload a file to a server and it says it was successful however it never transfers. I hard-coded some values for now, but here is the code:

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions(); 
options.fileKey = "file"; 
options.fileName = "readme.txt"; 
imageURI = "C:\\Users\\me\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\MyApp_68mjwy0kbd4mc\\LocalState\\readme.txt" 
options.mimeType = "text/plain"; 
options.httpMethod = "POST"; 
options.chunkedMode = false; 
var ft = new FileTransfer(); 

ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://example.com/upload/upload.php"), fileUploadWin, fileUploadFail, options);
```

When I look at fiddler I see that two file names are getting set:

-----------------------------7de36c253902b2 
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source";filename="readme.txt""; filename="blob" 
Content-Type: text/plain

This is a UTF-8 text file written using FileWriter.  I see the file on disk and it contains the base64 string i wrote to it.

Comment: What is the response from the server, as seen by Fiddler? Are the quotes really messed up like that in what you see in Fiddler or did you typo when posting here?

Comment: This is a copy and paste from fiddler.  This is actually a bug in cordova/phonegap.  I will most likely submit a pull request and then update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you are developing windows store apps try this one instead of filetransfer(phonegap)

using filepicker:

```
function uploadFile() {
var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
filePicker.fileTypeFilter.replaceAll(["*"]);

filePicker.pickSingleFileAsync().then(function (file) {
    if (!file) {
        printLog("No file selected");
        return;
    }

    var upload = new UploadOp();
    var uriString ="";//serverurl
    upload.start(uriString, file);

    // Store the upload operation in the uploadOps array.
    uploadOperations.push(upload);
});
}
```

using path:

```
 function uploadFile() {
// Asynchronously create the file in the Application Local folder.
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.getFileAsync("readme.txt").done(function (file) {

    var upload = new UploadOp();
    var uriString = document.getElementById("serverAddressField").value;
    upload.start(uriString, file);

    // Store the upload operation in the uploadOps array.
    uploadOperations.push(upload);
});
```

}

Comment: I want to stick with using PhoneGap's API.  This uses WinJS and will not work on other platforms.  Also you forgot the .(done) on the async call for a file.  Either way I am looking at a PhoneGap implementation.